# Combine data of OSM roads into longer lines using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

For my vector map I'd love to display highways at a quite early zoom level. The problem is that this data would be quite big, so I thought I simply `ST_Simplify` it. The problem though is that the OSM data consists of a lot of small road segments. So for Germany f.e. there are roughly 60000 segments of type `highway`.

Does anybody have an idea on how to better simplify the data? I was thinking of creating longer polylines by combining the small ones and then `ST_Simplify`-ing those?!?

The problem is just that I don't know how I should do that...

I could do a `ST_Union` on all of my roads, but that would create ONE geometry. So maybe group them somehow. There are relations in OSM, but I don't think that there is an easy query for "Give my only highway", right?

As a bonus, if would be awesome to have only a line in one direction, as for my zoom-level the two lines would look as one anyway.

Comment: why don't you think "that there is an easy query for "Give my only highway", right?"? doesn't your highway have a name or id?

Comment: I was refering to the relations. From the data I had a look at, it seems that highway relations are not really properly tagged in OSM.

Comment: Ignore relations, they won't help for your case. Relations are used in OSM to express specific routes, you are not looking for routes though. How about combining roads that share the same `name` and the same `ref`, if available? However note that roads can split while still keeping the same name (e.g. if there are separate roads for each direction, or at a roundabout, or ramps for motorways). So this won't work for all cases.